# How do I transfer tons of old email from Outlook Express to Gmail?

Tags: windows-xp, gmail, outlook-express

I use Outlook Express (V6) with several POP3 email accounts on my aging Windows XP laptop. Yes, I know I must be among the last dozen people using it in the world but I've never had cause to change as it's never caused me a single problem (is it the most reliable software Microsoft has ever produced?)

Anyway, I've had my laptop since 2002 and so have accumulated a ton of emails on it. I realise that my laptop (as reliable as it is) won't last forever but I'd like to keep my old emails 'live' and to hand in the future.

So, **is there some (easy) way to transfer my old emails (sent and received in various folders) from Outlook Express to, say, Gmail?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Make a backup of your emails.

Step 2: Add your GMail account to Outolook as an IMAP mailbox (not POP) and drag 'n drop the mails from your local mailfolders into the remote IMAP folders. I would not recommend to transfer all mails at once because the amount of data could be huge and I also don't know if Outlook can handle this. Better try this first with an few mails (e.g. 50) and if Outlook doesn't hang you can try more and more.

Comment: While this is painful, I would suggest this method too. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

[This guy](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/export-outlook-email-to-gmail-pst-backup/1938/) answered a question almost identical to what you're asking.